# Determining the path to Outlook.exe from java?

Tags: java, outlook

I want to invoke outlook from the command line (for various reasons) and wanted to know how I go about discovering the Path to the Outlook.exe file.

I'm pretty sure it's stored in the registry, but was wondering how to go about reading that from Java.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a [Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q240794/) that describes the procedure, just not in Java.

So I guess the question becomes how do I access the registry from java.

Comment: I suggest editing both your question and title, or starting a new question if the nature of your question has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this site](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/java-concepts/34-core-java/62-java-registry-wrapper.html) that might be able to help you. It's a Java Registry wrapper, seems to have a lot of features but no idea how robust the implementation is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Otis' answer the following code does it nicely.

```
static String getOutlookPath() {
  // Message message = new Message();
  final String classID;
  final String outlookPath;

  { // Fetch the Outlook Class ID
    int[] ret = RegUtil.RegOpenKey(RegUtil.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,   "SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Outlook.Application\\CLSID", RegUtil.KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
    int handle = ret[RegUtil.NATIVE_HANDLE];
    byte[] outlookClassID = RegUtil.RegQueryValueEx(handle, "");

    classID = new String(outlookClassID).trim(); // zero terminated bytes
    RegUtil.RegCloseKey(handle);
  }

  { // Using the class ID from above pull up the path
    int[] ret = RegUtil.RegOpenKey(RegUtil.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + classID + "\\LocalServer32", RegUtil.KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
    int handle = ret[RegUtil.NATIVE_HANDLE];
    byte[] pathBytes = RegUtil.RegQueryValueEx(handle, "");

    outlookPath = new String(pathBytes).trim(); // zero terminated bytes
    RegUtil.RegCloseKey(handle);
  }

  return outlookPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution modified slightly from a similar problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194710/854664
Notice I'm using .pst instead of .xls

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ShowOutlookInstalled {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "assoc", ".pst" });
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String extensionType = input.readLine();
            input.close();
            // extract type
            if (extensionType == null) {
                outlookNotFoundMessage("File type PST not associated with Outlook.");
            } else {
                String fileType[] = extensionType.split("=");

                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "ftype", fileType[1] });
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String fileAssociation = input.readLine();
                // extract path
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"");
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(fileAssociation);
                if (m.find()) {
                    String outlookPath = m.group(0);
                    System.out.println("Outlook path: " + outlookPath);
                } else {
                    outlookNotFoundMessage("Error parsing PST file association");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            outlookNotFoundMessage(err.getMessage());
        }


    }

    private static void outlookNotFoundMessage(String errorMessage) {
        System.out.println("Could not find Outlook: \n" + errorMessage);

    }
}
```